# System.out.println not working with threads when executed from console

Tags: java, multithreading, jar, console

I have an application which uses threads to run heavy tasks. When the thread ends its own task, it creates a file and sends a message using `System.out.println()`.

In Eclipse works fine, but once compiled into a *.jar* and called from console, it does not display anything. **However it creates correctly the files.**

What happends is, when i call the application via console, a new console prompt appears inmediatly, although the program is not finish yet (I know it because no file is being generated yet).

Comment: How are you executing the jar from the console?

Comment: Just with its name, like this: myApp.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is how you're executing the jar file. If you're just running it from Windows, it's probably being run with `javaw.exe` for example. Simply run it explicitly:

```
java -jar foo.jar
```

and all should be fine. This is unrelated to threads, by the way... it's just how jar files are executed.